# Spring Security for web service without roles and authorities

Tags: rest, spring-boot, web-services, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a REST web service built on Spring Boot. For authentication I use Spring Security and Basic Authentication and I am new to this. Do I have to use Roles and Authorities for my solution?

I only want the user of the web service to state user name and password credentials. I don't have any users in a database or elsewhere.

In my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configuration I now have `.authorities("ROLE_USER");` in the end of my configureGlobal method, following examples on the internet. I would like to skip that so that the class would look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("username").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I found I can not do that. I works if I use `.roles("USER")` instead. But I do not want to handle neither authorities nor roles, just a user name and a password.
Why do I need this or how can I skip this?

I am greatful for any light you can shed on this matter (authentication and Spring Security) to a novice.

Comment: [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle) is a good place to start reading on the topic. With spring boot all you need is the [dependency](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-maven-boot) and this [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#servlet-hello-starting) will help with your requirement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `inMemoryAuthentication` you normally provide the roles via `roles("...")`

InMemoryAuthentication does not work with `null` as GrantedAuthorities. So not calling `roles(...)` causes an `BeanCreationException`

But nothing prevents you from providing an **empty list**...  like:

```java
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("username")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles(); // <--- leave roles empty
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Note: Don't think you need `@EnableWebSecurity` or use `configureGlobal` ...

---

Or you can always choose to create your own custom AuthenticationProvider.

Configuration of a custom AuthenticationProvider:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
    }
```